# How come if I have logged into my website as a registered user I cannot access other pages after setting session rules?

Tags: php, session-variables

I am working on a project right now and I'm unable to access pages of my own profile if i have logged in as a user - I have set thisi rule at the top of each of my pages:

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
header("location:http://localhost/ci/web-project-jb.php/start");// If an unregistered user tries to manually navigate to any of my webpages they will be brought to 'start' page.
```

The start page has

```
 <$_SESSION['username'] = null;?>
```

just to make sure the session has been destroyed

I have set in my logout function that it will destroy session :

```
function logout()
{
$this->session->sess_destroy();
redirect ('start');
}
```

I have a session_start(); at my home page after I login (have it on my login page too) but since I've put the above if statement in i can no longer login as a registered user - why could this happen? I even have a  session_start called at the login page. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Where are you setting `$_SESSION['loggedin']` to `TRUE`?

Comment: Should this be set on every page?  session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'] == true)); 
   header("location:http://localhost/ci/web-project-jb.php/start");

?>

Comment: session_start() must be on every page you need to use $_SESSION, or in a php file that is included on every page.

Comment: Ok i've put this in - if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true)header("location:http://localhost/ci/web-project-jb.php/start");. But if now log successfully into homepage it gives me the error -  Undefined index: loggedin

Comment: The above can never be true.  You can't have `$_SESSION['loggedin']` not set, **and** have it also be `true`.

Comment: if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == false) - this is now bringing me to the start page even if the login detils are correct

Comment: Why would u think it's not bringing me to the homepage?

Comment: This is currently what Im trying: if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) == true)
   header("location:http://localhost/ci/web-project-jb.php/start"); no luck with it