# I cannot access my homepage after setting session rules - why is this?

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm unable to access pages of my own profile if i have logged in as a user - I have set this rule at the top of each of my pages:

login page:

```
  <?php  session_start();
   $password = $this->input->post('password');
   if($password == '1'){$_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;}
     ?>
```

User should then be brought to homepage:

```
<?php  session_start();
  if(! isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
  header("location:http://localhost/ci/web-project-jb.php/start");

?>
```

```
<div id="header">
  <h1> 
    SpaceBook: <?=$username?>'s Home Page
  </h1>
</div>
```

If an unregistered user tries to manually navigate to any of my webpages they will be brought to 'start' page:

```
 <?php  $_SESSION['username'] = null;?>
 <body id="start">

<div id="header">
<h1>
 SpaceBook: Start Page
</h1>
```

just to make sure the session has been destroyed

I have set in my logout function that it will destroy session :

```
 function logout()
{
$this->session->sess_destroy();
redirect ('start');
 }
```

I have a session_start(); at my home page after I login (have it on my login page too) but since I've put the above if statement in i can no longer login as a registered user - why could this happen? I even have a session_start called at the login page. I have a login controller too where I pass in my login parameters. Do i need o mention loggedin here?           Controller:

```
   function loguserin()

    {

$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5|trim');


$username = $this->input->post('username');
$password = $this->input->post('password');

$valid = $this->membership->validateUser($username, $password);

if ($this->form_validation->run() && $valid == true)
{
    $this->session->set_userdata('status', 'OK');
    $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);

    redirect('home');
}
else
{
    $this->session->set_userdata('status', 'NOT_OK');
    $this->load->view('shared/header');
    $this->load->view('account/logintitle');
    $this->load->view('account/loginview');
    $this->load->view('shared/footer');
    }
  }
```

Comment: `if(! isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) == true)` can just be `if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))`, You also need `session_start` at the top of any page that would be making a `$_SESSION` request.. so every page by the looks of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How come if I have logged into my website as a registered user I cannot access other pages after setting session rules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714265/how-come-if-i-have-logged-into-my-website-as-a-registered-user-i-cannot-access-o)

Comment: Is your login page actually sending the entered password? From what I can see, there is no place to actually login. `$this->input->post('password');` is most likely empty as you don't have a place to allow the user to login.

Comment: ive added this to my viewc page at the start: <?
if ($this->session->userdata('status')!='OK') 
{
 redirect('start');
}

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to be too valid. `if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))`should be fine for that line. When you say you want to reset the session, is it not better to just use `$this->session->sess_destroy();` instead of `<$_SESSION['username'] = null;?>`?

Finally, `<$_SESSION['username'] = null;?>` seems to be a resetting code. If you login then visit a page with this code, it would simply end the session... Are you sure you're not doing that?

Comment: <? session_start();
if(! isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
   header("location:http://localhost/ci/web-project-jb.php/start"); - I have this at the login screen the client is meant to see the homepage once theyve logged in but theyre still being bounced back to the start page - why is this? I only have <$_SESSION['username'] = null;?> on the start page itself. this is so the session will be over for sure when session destroy is doen through the logout option. What is the best way to overcome this?

Comment: Is `header("location:localhost/ci/web-project-jb.php/start";);` a different page than the start page; or is it the start page itself...?

Comment: <$_SESSION['username'] = null;?> is on the start page. header("location:localhost/ci/web-project-jb.php/start";) is the start page the client is bounced back to when anyone tries to navigate to homepage without logging in. Its the same same page. The header line features in the home page- they use a a seperate screen to login. My site starts with a start page then login screen then homepage

Comment: I see, so right now, it's the fact that the session isn't set properly and it's still assuming that the user is not logged in even after they are. Could you post the code for your login page? Make sure you have `session_start()` on all of the pages, and make sure the `$_SESSION['loggedin']` variable is properly set before redirecting the user to the homepage.

Comment: Here is my login page - <?php  session_start();?> - that's all i have for the login page since this isnt a page thats blocked from navigating to. But maybe as you are saying Im not setting the loggedin variable properly. Here is the homepage: <?php  session_start();
if(! isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
   header("location:http://localhost/ci/web-project-jb.php/login");

?>
<body id="home">
    
    <div id="header">
      <h1> 
        SpaceBook: <?=$username?>'s Home Page
      </h1>
   How would I properly set the loggedin variable on my login or homepage?

Comment: There's your problem. Your login page doesn't actually have a script to set the variable. So I suggest you finish making your login page. When a user logs in, you have to set the `$_SESSION['loggedin']` variable. Eg: `<?php if($passwordCorrect == 1){$_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;}?>` Then, you can redirect to the homepage.

Comment: I put this in my login page - <?php  session_start();
$password = $this->input->post('password');
if($password == 1){$_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;}

?> Yet if I login it still, yes brings me back to the start page

Comment: `if($password == 1)` should be `if($password == '1')`. We need to stop our extended discussion. Please post the code from ALL of your pages on your original question and I'll take a look.